# Dynamically load and clear content of LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have the following scenario: I have a LinearLayout on which I then add "cards" to which is a custom class which extends LinearLayout.

The problem is that each card contains an image. Now if I have too many cards to display I get an out of memory error because of the size of the images.

How can I dynamically see which cards are currently displayed on the screen and only load the images of those cards and keep the rest null?

I am struggling to detect which card is currently displayed on the screen and which ones are not. And then also to have an event load and clear images as the user scrolls though the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement a RecyclerView, which does the job for you.

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    final Adapter adapter = new Adapter();

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The adapter:

```
private class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_main, viewGroup, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) 
        // set the content of the card
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return // number of cards
    }

}
```

The ViewHolder

```
private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView text;
    public TextView text2;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(/* your textView */);
        text2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(/* another textView */);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(/* an image */);

    }
}
```

The Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

For something like this, you should probably use a Recycler View. This way you can recycle the views and ideally not run into memory issues and not have to have hacky solutions that check what is on the screen and what isn't.